# Keeping Wi-Fi internet connected with ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) enabled to share across ethernet

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, ethernet

I'm sharing my Wi-Fi internet over ethernet using ICS (Internet Connection Sharing). I have two problems with that:

**Problem 1:** My PC doesn't automatically connect to the Internet over Wi-Fi after startup. I have to connect it manually.
**Problem 2:** The manual connection persists for hours, but it disconnects after that, requiring manual connection yet again.

Neither of those problems occur when I disable the ICS. In fact, the Wi-Fi internet connects automatically as soon as I disable ICS. And when I re-enable ICS, it again disconnects after like 5 minutes, by itself.

Everything works perfectly fine for hours after manually connecting to the internet (until the problem 2 occurs).

So far, I have tried the following:

1. Set custom network interface metrics. Wi-Fi to 20 (from the default 50), and ethernet to 55 (from the default 25).
2. Set the same metrics to the `Local Area Connection* 10` and `... 9` interfaces which seems to correspond to Wi-Fi and ethernet, respectively. (I don't really know what these two are.)
3. Disabled IPv6 on the ethernet adapter.
4. Enabled/disabled "Allow other network users to control or disable the shared Internet connection" option (the second option in the ICS settings).

How can I fix the ICS so that my problems are resolved?

---

My network setup is as follows:

```
Internet --[Coax cable]-- ISP modem/router --[Wi-Fi]-- PC --[Ethernet]-- VR router --[Wi-Fi]-- VR headset
```

The labels within square brackets indicate the medium of connection, and the rest are the network entities. Notably, the ethernet connection from my PC to my VR router is into the router's WAN port.

The VR router is running in the Access Point mode.

The two subnetworks hosted by the ISP modem/router and my PC are disjoint. My PC has two different IP addresses on both those networks and is the default gateway on the latter.